# Ansible set_fact jinja2 for mapping a list and integer

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to compose a "set_fact" statement in Ansible which basically tries to map a list value with corresponding integer in the same item output variables. I am facing syntactical errors in referencing the appending and evaluating expressions to bind the list values with corresponding value(another value)

I have already tried as shown in the code snippet to use map with lambda to map the values. Basically the "results" are in the format.

results=[{_ansible_item_label=[0, item1], status=int1}, {_ansible_item_label=[0, item2], status=int2}, {_ansible_item_label=[0, item3], status=int3}]

```
- name: Matching item to values
      set_fact:
        append: "{{ append|default([]) + map(lambda x, y: x+ ':' +y, item._ansible_item_label, item.status) }}"
      with_items: "{{results|list}}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item._ansible_item_label}}"
      register: append
```

Expected Data Type: Dictionary
Expected Result: { "item1": "int1", "item2": "int2", "item3": "int3" } and if there is no value for status, how can we efficiently handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you can use a lambda with map in jinja (but I'll be happily proven wrong). Anyway, there is no need for that. As you'll see below, you can achieve your result with simple ansible expressions.

Then, you have an implementation error: registering the result of `set_fact` with the same var you are already setting will override the content with the result of running set_fact (i.e. success + all other info).

To handle the elements without status, you simply use `default`.

Here is the test playbook I made:

```
---
- name: Create dictionary from other 
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    result:
      - _ansible_item_label:
          - 0
          - item1
        status: int1
      - _ansible_item_label:
          - 0
          - item2
        status: int2
      - _ansible_item_label:
          - 0
          - item3

  tasks:
    - name: Create other dict
      set_fact:
        append: >-
          {{
            append
            | default([])
            | combine({item._ansible_item_label.1: item.status|default('no status')})
          }}
      loop: "{{ result }}"

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: append
```

And the result

```
PLAY [Create dictionary from other] *********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create other dict] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'_ansible_item_label': [0, 'item1'], 'status': 'int1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'_ansible_item_label': [0, 'item2'], 'status': 'int2'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'_ansible_item_label': [0, 'item3']})

TASK [Show result] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "append": {
        "item1": "int1",
        "item2": "int2",
        "item3": "no status"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks !!